# How to show dropdown selected data in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to show the drop down selected value in textbox.

This is my design.

[image]

This is my php code for drop downlist...

```
<?php
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("storedb", $con);
 $s=mysql_query("select * from dealerdetail order by Dealer asc "); 
 ?>
   Select Dealer Name:

   <select name="dealer" id="dealer">
     <option value="">---- select Dealer -----</option>

     <?php 
while($dd=mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
    ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $dd['D_id'] ?>"><?php echo $dd['Dealer'] ?></option>
     <?php 
}
?>
   </select>
```

Please help.

Comment: Where is your js code? you can use change event of selecbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
$('#dealer').val(); //return selected value
$( "#dealer option:selected" ).text() // return selected options text
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the change event and text property of select box to access the value

```
$('#dealer').change(function () {
                $("#idOfTextBox").val($("#dealer option:selected").text());
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery:

Live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/t6YHK/25/

```
$('#dealer').change(function () {
  $("#your_input_id").val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#dealer").change(function(){
$("textarea").val( $(this).val() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS

http://angularjs.org/

Scroll down to below the black area.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're taking your first steps in web development, and for this, i strictly recommend that you stop using DreamWeaver to learn more about the code and how things go.

Each element in your web page is in the DOM (see [HTML Document Object Model](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)). So using native javascript all of your elements using :

```
document.getElementById("elementId")
```

And this is ALL what you need. All other solutions using frameworks will use this line of code whether you see this or not.

so for your specific question we will create a javascript function to be used in the event of value change of your dropdown list (assuming your text field's `id` is `myText`)

```
function updateMyText()
{
    var dd = document.getElementById("myDropDown");
    var ddtext = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("myText").value = ddtext;
}
```

to call it when a dropdown list item is selected you need the attribute `onchange`

```
   <select name="dealer" id="dealer" onchange='updateMyText()'>
```